# Why the type info is lost here in scala?

Tags: scala

Here's the signature the method:

```
  def runJob[T, U: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[T], func: Iterator[T] => U): Array[U] = {
    runJob(rdd, func, 0 until rdd.partitions.length)
  }
```

Then I try to invoke it like this, but the compilation fails. It seems it can not recognize the int type. why's that ? And if I write it as the second way, it works, very weird, am I miss something there ?

```
sc.runJob(rdd, (iter:Iterator[Int]) => 1)(0)

<console>:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Int]
         val a=sc.runJob(rdd, (iter:Iterator[Int])=>1)(0)


val a= sc.runJob(rdd, (iter:Iterator[Int]) => 1)
a(0)  // works
```

Comment: sc.runJob(rdd, (iter:Iterator[Int]) => 1).head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using TypeTag/ClassTag in template argument, compiler will generate a implicit parameter of the typetag specified.

So the actual signature of your `runJob` should be:

```
def runJob[T, U: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[T], func: Iterator[T] => U)(implicit ClassTag[U]): Array[U]
```

The compiler consider the extra Int argument as the ClassTag, the second way the compiler auto fill the implicit argument, so it works.

Comment: I'd add that the way to avoid it is `sc.runJob(rdd, (iter:Iterator[Int]) => 1).apply(0)`.